# VSCode "Show Fixes" in a different language than text editor itself

Tags: visual-studio-code

My entire VS Code is in English, but sometimes some of the fixes under "Show fixes" appear in Polish. I would like to switch to English entirely. How can I do that?

I have already switched my language under "Configure Display Language" to en. I've also tried downloading an English extension but it failed too. Is there an option that I missed that sets the language of (some) of the fixes to my default OS system?

[One in English, one in Polish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDe02.png)

Comment: delete the polish language file from the extension that provides the Fix, or search its settings to switch to Eng, or ask the developer to add that setting

Comment: @rioV8 There are no language settings in the extension. Also, all of the items in my languagepacks.json file (and elsewhere, eg. Configure Display Language) are set to English.

Comment: the extensions can have language files, which extension suggests that fix and then look in the source of it